# What is Hadoop trash checkpoint for?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I don't understand what the purpose of creating checkpoint in Hadoop trash, then I did a simple test.

- I set the fs.trash.interval property 10 minutes in core-site.xml.
- I deleted a file in HDFS and it was moved to .Trash/Current.
- I waited for a little more than 10 mins to check the result in Trash.

But I see that it was moved to checkpoint folder after about 7 minutes.

[image: Image: delete file and check in trash]

[image: Image: view checkpoint in trash]

After a little more than 10 minutes, file was removed permanently in Trash.

[image: Image: file will be deleted permanently]

1) My first question is what the purpose of checkpoint here is.

Then I set fs.trash.checkpoint.interval property 3 minutes in core-site.xml.

[image: Image: core-site.xml configuration]

I deleted a file in HDFS and after about 3 minutes it was moved to checkpoint folder.
And after about 10 minutes, the trash was also empty.
If I use the command 'hdfs dfs -expunge, file is moved to checkpoint folder immediately.

2) My second question is finally file will be permanently deleted after 10 minutes, so what is the purpose of setting 'fs.trash.checkpoint.interval'

Comment: Read this? https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2015/10/22/hdfs-trash/

Answer (score 4):

Checkpointing is just a way to not periodically clean *the whole Trash folder*, all in one swoop.

`fs.trash.interval` is what actually deletes the files.

`fs.trash.checkpoint.interval` is moving from `Current` to checkpoint folders.

> `fs.trash.interval`
>   **Default**: 0
>   **Description**: Number of minutes after which the checkpoint gets deleted. If zero, the trash feature is disabled. This option may be
>   configured both on the server and the client. If trash is disabled
>   server side then the client side configuration is checked. If trash is
>   enabled on the server side then the value configured on the server is
>   used and the client configuration value is ignored.
>
> `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval`
>   **Default**: 0
>   **Description**: Number of minutes between trash checkpoints. Should be smaller or equal to `fs.trash.interval`. If zero, the value is set to
>   the value of `fs.trash.interval`. Every time the checkpointer runs it
>   creates a new checkpoint out of current and removes checkpoints
>   created more than `fs.trash.interval` minutes ago

Answer (score 2):

From the source code of "org.apache.hadoop.fs.TrashPolicyDefault",

```
Files are moved to a user's trash directory, a subdirectory of their home 
directory named ".Trash".  Files are initially moved to a <i>current</i> 
sub-directory of the trash directory. Within that sub-directory their original 
path is preserved.  Periodically one may checkpoint the current trash and 
remove older checkpoints.  (This design permits trash management without 
enumeration of the full trash content, without date support in the filesystem, 
and without clock synchronization.)
```

https://github.com/hopshadoop/hops/blob/master/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TrashPolicyDefault.java